# Document Library view that filters on enterprise keywords

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, view, enterprise-keywords

I have created a document library, enabled Enterprise Keywords, uploaded documents, added enterprise keywords to them

I have added the keyword *Farnarkle* to one document along with some other keywords, If I search on this keyword it finds the document.

Now I want to create a document library view based on *Enterprise Keyword=Farnarkle*

I created a *`Standard View`* against the document library, and in the filter section I selected this option:

```
"Show Items only when the following is true"

"Show the items when the column Enterprise Keywords is equal to Farnarkle"
```

But when I go back to the document library and select the view, it's empty.

I can't use *`contains`* instead of *`is equal to`* because I get the error:

> The filter type cannot be used with this type of column. You can apply the 'contains' operator only to columns that have the type Single line of text ..... blah blah blah

I think *`is equal to`* should be fine since it's a multivalue type column

Does anyone know how to create a document library view based on Enterprise Keywords?

Comment: So no one knows the answer to this? All I've had is one bad edit which I couldn't reject.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my site - the filter works as expected. Enterprise keywords are enabled and are multiple select. The caml query looks like this <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="TaxKeyword" /><Value Type="Text">FilterValue</Value></Eq></Where>

Comment: OK so as far as you can see, Enterprise keywords _are_ searchable by default from the vanilla search box?

Comment: The default search box in the library works and searches through the enterprise keywords field. I know that because I have a typo in one of the keywords and when I search by it, I only get that 1 result that uses the misspelled word. Have you contacted Microsoft support?

Comment: Wow. I just searched again and this time I got a hit. It must've taken a little while to index. Sorry for wasting everyones time here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the same steps which you specified in your question, and I am able to create the `Document Library` view based on the Enterprise keyword. I am also verifying on SharePoint Online.

Here I am sharing my output screen snaps.

The condition which I used, I filtered where Keyword is **Test**

[image: Condition]

The Output View:

[image: Output view of document library]

So please ensure your condition.

Comment: Yes you're right. I just realised that the problem is that the file is in a subfolder. I was expecting to see it from the root folder but if it's a few folders deep you need to drill in to find it. So yes it works, just not as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't try to use a filter/search web part to  filter/search the library content by enterprise keywords ?

As the following steps

- At your view page , Add a Text Filter Web Part under Filters Categories.
- Open the Web Part edit menu and choose Connections >Send Filter Values To  >your Library.
- Choose Connection dialog, Connection Type: `Get Filter Values From`, click Configure.
- Select  `Consumer Field Name`: Enterprise Keywords, click finish.
- Stop page Editing.
- Enter a default value in the Default Value box as `Farnarkle`
- At Appearance, Set Chrome as none to hide it.

Comment: Thanks - it'll take me a few days to try this. I'm surprised this field isn't searched automatically though.

Comment: So I rechecked and the Enterprise Keywords boxes are now being recognised but thanks anyway.

Comment: great , what was the issue ?

Comment: I don't know but I'm guessing I didn't wait long enough for it to index the documents. I entered the keyword and searched about 10 minutes later.. it's now about a week later :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. The problem in the end was that I assumed that a folder view applied at the root would make document appear that were in subfolders.

Comment: you are welcome ,in my answer  I only assumed that you ask about a workaround for Does anyone knows how to create a document library view based on Enterprise Keywords? this what you said in your quest, and I answered regarding this, anyway, it's great to know your issue and solve it , good luck my bro

Comment: It turns out I had made the correct document view all along, but I was in the wrong folder. For some reason I thought the view would pick all documents out of the entire library. Reading your answer again, it seems like that might work - I do apologise as I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Please don't apologize, you don't need to say that ,  you are welcome at any time , our only goal is to solve your issue and this is done , good job my bro :)